Como hacer click en input con Selenium y Pyhton?
Tengo este form y necesito hacer click en el input con type=button y value=CASTRO SALVADOR
<form name="seleccionaEmpresaForm" action="setearContribuyente.do">
<table width="50%" align="center">
<tbody><tr><td height="5"></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center"><b>Seleccione la Empresa a representar:</b></td></tr>
<tr><td height="5"></td></tr>
<tr>
   <td align="center">
           <input type="hidden" name="idContribuyente" id="idcontribuyente">
               <input type="button" class="btn_empresa ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="width:100%" value="CASTRO SALVADOR" onclick="document.getElementById('idcontribuyente').value='0';document.seleccionaEmpresaForm.submit();" role="button">
   </td>
</tr>
<tr><td height="5"></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>

Este es mi codigo.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

# Configura el driver de Selenium para Firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Navega a la página de login del sistema de AFIP
driver.get("https://auth.afip.gov.ar/contribuyente_/login.xhtml?action=SYSTEM&system=admin_mono")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "F1:username"))).send_keys("xxxxxx")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "F1:btnSiguiente"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "F1:password"))).send_keys("xxxxx")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "F1:btnIngresar"))).click()

# Espera para asegurar que la sesión se haya iniciado correctamente
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_contains("monotributo.afip.gob.ar"))

# Navega a la página de facturación
driver.get("https://monotributo.afip.gob.ar/app/Facturacion.aspx")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "bBtn1")))

# Hace clic en el botón inicial en la página de facturación
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "bBtn1"))).click()

# Espera hasta que el elemento sea visible y no solo presente:
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='CASTRO SALVADOR']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
button.click()

Para intentar hacer click intente:
boton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.btn_empresa[value='CASTRO SALVADOR']")
boton.click()

A su vez intente tambien:
boton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.btn_empresa.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all")
boton.click()

Tambien use:
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn_empresa' and @value='CASTRO SALVADOR']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

Use SelectorsHub como para verificar que el XPATH este bien, a su vez use CSS SELECTOR.
No se si estoy haciendo algo mal o por el simple hecho de que el boton usa JAVASCRIPT y no lo se levantar con Python.
Alguien sabe como hacer?
